# code=DotfulBucketNameNotUnderTld for .name domain

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In order to portion off my part of the Google Cloud Storage namespace, I've verified my domain, `paul.kishimoto.name`, [as described here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming#verification). However, I am still unable to create buckets containing that name. Using the `gsutil` command-line tool, I am given an error message:

```
$ gsutil mb -p khaeru-private gs://paul.kishimoto.name-documents
Creating gs://paul.kishimoto.name-documents/...
GSResponseError: status=400, code=DotfulBucketNameNotUnderTld, reason=Bad Request.
```

A search for the error code `DotfulBucketNameNotUnderTld` turns up [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gs-discussion/oN-95qGBAvI/discussion) from the old support group, in which a Google employee said a list from publicsuffix.org was used to check for valid TLDs. The list does not appear to contain the `.name` TLD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After verifying that you own the domain paul.kishimoto.name you can create buckets with that name or subdomains of that name, such as paul.kishimoto.name, docs.paul.kishimoto.name, images.paul.kishimoto.name, etc. You can't create a bucket named paul.kishimoto.name-documents because .name-documents is not a currently valid TLD.

Mike Schwartz, Google Cloud Storage team

Comment: Thanks! I was applying a habit carried over from Amazon S3, and failed to read the documentation closely.